# How to add Line Editor command?

Tags: java

I needed help witing a program in Java that simulates a simple line editor which supports the following operations:

```
$insert
```

Each subsequent line, up to the next line editor command, will be inserted in the text. If there is a designated current line, each line is inserted before that current line. Otherwise each line is inserted at the end of the text.

```
$delete m n
```

Each line in text between lines m and n inclusively will be deleted

So far i started my program as follows:

It allows me to ask for the user what line they want to enter and uses a link list method to add lines, I believe, and now I am not sure as to what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

There are certain restrictions that i have to follow as well:

- Check for incorrect commands and their parameters and  display appropriate messages. For example, if there is no the 10th line in the text and the user types line 10, an error message should be displayed.
- Use a linked list to store all text provided by the user. All commands of this simplified line editor begin with a $ symbol.
- If the syntax of a command is incorrect, display an error message and let the user try again.
- Having received the command insert, if the first letter of the next line is not a $ symbol, treat it as a line of text, and store it in a node of the linked list. Use StringTokenizer to process a line of text word by  word if needed.
- Always display a message "Please enter a command or a line of text" after a command or a line of text is received . Always indicate the current line in a displayed text. The default current line is the first line, and the first line is numbered as line 1.
- You cannot use the built-in list package

---

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program_4 
{
    public static Node head;                      //this is me

```
public class Node                //from ppt
{
    String data;
    Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        data="";
        next=null;
    }

    public Node(String x, Node n)
    {
        data=x;
        next=n;
    }
}


public void BuildList()                    //from ptt
{
    int line_no=1;
    Node q = new Node("",null);
    head=q;
    String oneLine;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader indata = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                   //read data from terminal
        System.out.println("Please Choose a Command From the List:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("$insert");
        System.out.println("$delete m n");
        System.out.println("$print m n");
        System.out.println("$line m");
        System.out.println("$search String");
        System.out.println("$done");
        System.out.println("NOTE: m and n are line number parameters and string is a word you wish to search for");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        oneLine=indata.readLine();
        int x=0;
        while(!oneLine.equals("$done"))
        {
            String[] array=oneLine.split(" ");                 //breaks the command into an array 0,1,2
            if(array[0].equals("$insert"))
            {

                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Text (Enter $ if you wish to terminate)");
                oneLine=indata.readLine();
                while(!oneLine.equals("$"))
                {
                    String line_number = String.valueOf(line_no);                        
                    Node p = new Node(line_number +" " + oneLine, null);
                    q.next=p;
                    q=p;
                    line_no++;
                    x++;
                    oneLine=indata.readLine();
                }
            }
            else if(array[0].equals("$delete"))
            {
                q=head.next;
                Node z = new Node(q.data,q);
                for(int i=1; i<x; i++)
                {
                    String[] line=q.data.split(" ");
                    int lower_bound=Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
                    int lower_bound_2=Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    if(lower_bound==(lower_bound_2+1))
                    {
                         z=q;

                         break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q=q.next;
                    }
                }
                for(int i=1; i<x;i++)
                {

                    String[] line=q.data.split(" ");
                    if(line[0].equals(array[2]))
                    {
                        z.next=q.next;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q=q.next;
                    }
                }


                    //System.out.println(z.next.data);
            }
            else if(array[0].equals("$print"))
            {
                q=head.next;
                if(array.length>1)
                {
                    int lower_bound = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
                    int upper_bound = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
                    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
                    {
                        String[] line=q.data.split(" ");
                        if(line[0].equals(array[1]))
                        {

                            while(lower_bound<=upper_bound)
                            {
                                System.out.println(q.data);
                                q=q.next;
                                lower_bound++;

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            q=q.next;
                        }
                }

                }
                else
                {
                    while(q!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(q.data);
                        q=q.next;      
                    }          
                }






                //see if the first array[0] is equal to m 
                //if it is print it out from m to n by creating a variable and doing n-m
                //else q=q.next and run look again until q=!=null

            }
            else if(oneLine.equals("$line"))
            {
                System.out.println("This portion is working");
            //code here for current line
            }
            else if(array[0].equals("$search"))
            {
                System.out.println("This portion is working");
                //code here for search string
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect command");
                System.out.println("Please re-enter your Command");
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter your next command");
            oneLine=indata.readLine();

        }
        System.out.println("The program is done");

    }        
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error --" + e.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Program_4 mylist = new Program_4();
   mylist.BuildList();
  // mylist.print_list(head);
```

Comment: What help do you want?

Comment: Please ask specific questions that lead us to the problems you are having. We can't solve problems if we don't know what they are.

Comment: @pinoyyid I need help correcting the java code so i can delete certain lines #'s from what the user will input into the file. I was able to modify the code even more to help but i am still stuck. For example If I write the following 3 lines: Hello. How are you doing. Im doing fine.   I want it so if the user types $delete 2 then the program will delete the second line and the output will show: Hello. Im doing fine.

Comment: @Daemon I edited the code more to help with my specific question which i posted right above this post. Please let me know if you need any more further clarification.

Comment: I think this question belongs on freelancer.com